Let $G$ be a group of order $p^nq$ where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes and suppose $q \nmid p^i-1$ for $1 \leq i \leq n-1$. Prove $G$ is solvable
This is an extension of this post. Let $G$ be a group of order $p^nq$ where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes and suppose $q \nmid p^i-1$ for $1 \leq i \leq n-1$. Prove that $G$ is solvable.
This can be done by showing that $n_p=n_q=1$. Now, $n_p \equiv 1 \mod p$ and $n_p \mid q$. Then $n_p \in \{1,q\}$. But $p$ and $q$ are primes so $n_p \neq q$ because $q \neq 1 \mod p$ (if $p=2$ and $q=3$, then we use the hypothesis taht $q \nmid p-1$). So $n_p=1$.
To see $n_q=1$, note that since $q$ divides $|G|$, $G$ has a cyclic subgroup of order $q$, namely one that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_q$. This is a Sylow $q$ subgroup of $G$. By Sylow's $2$nd, $G$ acts on its Sylow $q$ subgroups by conjugation. But $\mathbb{Z}_q$ is abelian, hence normal, hence unique. Thus, $n_q=1$ and so $G$ is solvable.
Does this appear okay? I had doubts about the section where I expose us to $\mathbb{Z}_q$ since I'm normally used to counting elements. But counting elements fell short here.

I'm afraid almost everything is incorrect
You are correct that the number of $q$-Sylow subgroups must be $1$. However, your argument via the claim "but $\mathbb{Z}_q$ is abelian, hence normal, hence unique" is false. Abelian subgroups do not have to be normal; even abelian Sylow subgroups do not have to be normal. You may have confused "abelian" with "central", and you have no warrant to assume that the $q$-Sylow subgroups are central.
Instead, you should be using the hypothesis that $q\nmid p^i-1$ for $1\leq i\leq n$: we knowt $n_q$ must divide $p^n$ and be congruent to $1$ modulo $q$; thus we must have $n_q\equiv p^i$ for some $i$, $0\leq i\leq n$ to meet the divisibility condition; and since $p^i\equiv 1\pmod{q}$ implies $q\mid p^i-1$, your hypothesis excludes all values of $i$ except for $i=0$).
That is enough to establish the solvability of $G$: once you know the $q$-Sylow $Q$ is normal, then $G/Q$ is a $p$-group and hence solvable (nilpotent even), so that $G$ has a solvable normal subgroup $Q$ (which is abelian) with a solvable quotient $G/Q$, hence $G$ is solvable.
I also do not agree with your argument about $n_p$ always being equal to $1$. For starters, it is false that the only time when $q$ can be congruent to $1$ modulo $p$ is when $p=2$ and $q=3$. In fact, for any odd prime $q$ you have $q\equiv 1\pmod{2}$, so a group of order $2^nq$ would also have to be considered. And you can have $q\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ with both $p$ and $q$ odd: for instance, the $p=3$ and $q=7$. Your claim that $n_p=1$ is just false, because if it were true it would imply that any group of odd order $pq$ with $p\lt q$, or $p^2q$ with $p^2\lt q$, is necessarily abelian (since it would be isomorphic to the direct product of two abelian subgroups), and we know for a fact this is not the case. For example, there are nonabelian groups of order $21=3\times 7$, which satisfy your hypothesis (and are solvable), but for which $n_3\neq 1$.
